# Macbook pro 13 inch 2019 intel can it get PD charge if draws from 5 A source

Tags: macbook-pro, charger, intel

Just as the title suggest.

I want to know if the PD charge from charger is possible .
As 100 watt charge only does pd  by 20 V/5 A
And my old charger only has 3A power draw

Can I use  a 100 watt USB c from ugreen to charge my laptop
Laptop is MacBook pro 13 inch 2019 (with the i5 processor and 2 thunderbolt port?)

Comment: You can use a 100W charger, but it won't charge faster than the 60W charger.